# Technical term for a while loop

Tags: shell, loops

Both the commands mentioned below will return the same results.
These are simple while loops.

I will like to know what the second command is called in technical terms.

```
# cat /etc/passwd | while read i ; do awk -F':' '{print $1}'; done;

# while read i ; do awk -F':' '{print $1}'; done < /etc/passwd
```

The examples of technical terms are "globbing", "process substitution", etc.

I will like to know what do the experts call this type of programming (mentioned on second line above)

Comment: Note that the all can be rewritten as just `awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd`

Comment: More like scripting, rather than programming. Script is a high level instruction for another program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called input redirection:

```
some_cmd < /etc/passwd
```

You can read more about it in the **Redirecting Input** section in `man bash`.

On the other hand this is a pipeline:

```
cat /etc/passwd | some_cmd
```

You can read more about it in the **Pipelines** section in `man bash`.

The outcome of both of these examples is roughly the same, but the first example is usually better, because it's calling one less process (no need for a `cat` there).